# Getting values out of the JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON structure like below.

```
  {"name":"user1","param":{"showid":"test"}}
```

I will pass the value of JSON structure to a program where the values of the JSON object will be fetch out.
But the key values will differ for each JSON object.
SO i couldnt create a structure for the JSON object to retrieve the values.

ie :  The next time the JSON object may be like below.

```
  {"name1":"user2","param1":{"showname":"test1"}}
```

How to iterate the key value pair from the JSON structure in c#?

Comment: Parse it with any json library? Google hurts?

Comment: The JSON structure will be created in Javascript and in the other end i need to iterate it in C# without using any third party reference.

Comment: Without using third party reference you need to read json specs and write your own parser. But I think it's not the best idea, why can't use thirdparty?

Comment: If you're not going to use a third-party library, then use a `DataContractJsonSerializer` or otherwise parse it yourself then.

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing you do not need to know structure of JSON to parse it ...

Comment: without using any thirdparty im able to parse the JSON object using the JavaScriptSerializer. Now I have the JSON object through which i need to traverse and find out the relevant information.

Comment: I dont want to use any third party reference.

Answer (score 4):

You can use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer (System.Web.Extensions.dll) and load it into a datatype "dynamic", then you can access the properties like a dictionary.

Or you can use reflection to find the available properties/fields, and get a field's/property's value.

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> ToPropertyDictionary(this object obj)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        if (propertyInfo.CanRead && propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
            dictionary[propertyInfo.Name] = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
    return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: my program developed in .net 3.5 where dynamic keyword not supported. Can you please provide some sample code which how to achieve this using reflection?

Comment: public class JsonDeserializer
    {
        private IDictionary<string, object> jsonData { get; set; }

        public static Dictionary<string, object> ToPropertyDictionary(this object obj)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                if (propertyInfo.CanRead && propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                    dictionary[propertyInfo.Name] = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
            return dictionary;
        }   Can you figure out why getting error here?

Comment: @user833985: obj == null ?